# Get data from a View using a Endpoint written in Java

Tags: sql, view, endpoint

Usually when i write an endpoint I am used to just ask "SELECT * FROM table".
Instead now i am trying to extract data from a view. On PHP My admin usually run "SELECT * FROM view ", and it return me the view.
If i run the same from endpoint it dosn't return me anything or better an empty list.
How can i resolve it?

I want it to return the table as it happen when i write it form db

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem to select from a view. But remember that the view SQL query code is stored so to mantain it update you must use such as procedure which is served by an event/trigger to manitain it update